# npm v6 uninstalling the older version globally when newer version installation fails

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Current Behavior:

I installed the most recent version of my Node JS project on top of the older one without uninstalling it.
In the latest release, I added a preinstall script that verifies the local Node version and aborts the installation if it does not match.
Note: Installing my Node JS project globally every time

I see the process happening here is

loadIdealTree
Uninstalling the previous version of my project

```
npm timing action: extract Completed in 712ms
npm info lifecycle olevel@2.2.1~preuninstall: olevel@2.2.1
npm info lifecycle oleveli@2.2.1~uninstall: olevel@2.2.1
npm verb unbuild rmStuff olevel@2.2.1 from /Users/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/lib/node_modules
```

It starts installing the new version after uninstalling the older one globally.
The latest version requires Node 18; however, because I did not update the Node version to 18, my local installation will fail.

Now, the installation of a newer version on my local machine has failed, and the earlier version was removed before installing the newer version, therefore I do not have the version on my machine.

There is no rollback mechanism here. Could you please tell me what steps I'm missing or if this is expected behaviour?

preinstall script:

```
  try {
   nodeversionCheck();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
```

Expected Behavior:

When the installation of the newer version fails due to the preinstall script, the previous version should not be deleted globally in the system.

node version - 12.22.1
npm version - 6.14.2